# OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn method behave differently on same input

Tags: c#, security, cookies, token, owin

Can someone explain this?

I am using Owin Cookie Authentication and in my method I have the following code:

```
e.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(/* AuthenticationProperties, ClaimsIdentity */);
```

e is **CookieValidateIdentityContext**

When I have this method in my code, site asks for my credentials if I haven't sent a request for 30 minutes, but if I sent request (for example) every 20 minutes, then I am not asked to enter credentials.

When I don't have this method then I am not asked for credentials for 1 day because ExpireTimeSpan is set to 1440 minutes.

So my question is: What is happening inside the code above, and how I can prevent to log in again if I don't send a request for 30 minutes.

I'm using Microsoft.Owin.Sequrity 3.0

link to Owin method: [public void SignIn](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/release/src/Microsoft.Owin/Security/AuthenticationManager.cs) row:203

Comment: how your sign in code looks like?

Comment: @cuongle It is normal sign in page, the problem is that I am redirected there if I don't send a request for 30 minutes (which I set 30 minutes in my config file) .
*And that only happens if I have this line here

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your problem if you don't show your code

Comment: Sorry @cuongle I was in a rush, didn't understand your question well. 
this is my sign in code: (new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = e.Properties.IsPersistent }, principal)  where principal is the result of await manager.CreateIdentityAsync()

Answer (score 1):

You can add Expired time into your `AuthenticationProperties`, like below:

```
SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties 
{ 
    IsPersistent = e.Properties.IsPersistent,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1440)
}, principal);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help @cuongle